# middleware function for every component in react-router while rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-router

For every component that loads, I need to check if the cookie exists or not, but I am getting this error while rendering the `this.requireLogin` function:

> the **Loading** component is not defined.

```
class App extends Component {
  requireLogin = (component) => {
    // checking cookie Exists
    if(!cookieExist){
      axios.get("api/login")
        .then(res => window.location.assign(res.data))
        .catch(err => console.log("error occured on login service", err))
        return <div><Loading /></div>
      }else{
       return <${component} />
      }
    }

  render() {
    return(
      <BrowserRouter> 
        <Header />
        <div className="content">
          <Route path="/aboutus" render={() => this.requireLogin("AboutUs")} />
          <Route path="/contact" render={() => this.requireLogin("Contact")/>
          <Route path="/" render={() => this.requireLogin("HomePage")}
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you are importing the `Loading` component.

Comment: yes i have already imported that one , if i write without function i able to do it, but for every route component i need to repeat the code. Thats why i wrapped into a function so it can act as a middleware

Comment: All three route have this error?And there is a syntax error in the first route, it's this.requireLogin not this.requirLogin.@DILEEPTHOMAS

Comment: it was a typo while asking the question ? @Root whenever i am calling the method  its shows redirecting component is undefined, but i import the component

Comment: The render method of the Route component expects a react component to be returned. In your case it returns undefined, since the authentication is an asynchronous operation. You could create a separate RequireLogin component that fires the authentication check and render whatever component passed in.

Comment: @hbentlov in the question you can see the return of <div><Loading /></div> when the axios call is initiated. so i think when the mean time it should load the <Loading /> component which throws me the error undefined ?

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS Sorry, didn't notice the return statement, ignore my comment :-). The only reason i can think of you're getting that error would be that the Loading component is not imported (or exported) correctly.